# E2010 Incompatible types: 'string' and 'TStrings' принтер по умолчанию

Tags: delphi

```
procedure SetDefaultPrinter2(PrinterName: string);
var
  I: Integer;
  Device: PChar;
  Driver: PChar;
  Port: PChar;
  HdeviceMode: THandle;
  aPrinter: TPrinter;
begin
  Printer.PrinterIndex := -1;
  GetMem(Device, 255);
  GetMem(Driver, 255);
  GetMem(Port, 255);
  aPrinter := TPrinter.Create;
  try
    for I := 0 to Printer.Printers.Count - 1 do
    begin
      if Printer.Printers = PrinterName then
      begin
        aprinter.PrinterIndex := i;
        aPrinter.getprinter(device, driver, port, HdeviceMode);
        StrCat(Device, ',');
        StrCat(Device, Driver);
        StrCat(Device, Port);
        WriteProfileString('windows', 'device', Device);
        StrCopy(Device, 'windows');
        SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_WININICHANGE,
          0, Longint(@Device));
      end;
    end;
  finally
    aPrinter.Free;
  end;
  FreeMem(Device, 255);
  FreeMem(Driver, 255);
  FreeMem(Port, 255);
end;
```

Нашел код установки принтера по умолчанию, ругается.

```
[DCC Error] Unit3.pas(437): E2010 Incompatible types: 'string' and 'TStrings'
```

и вообще что делать в такой ситуации?

Comment: @big-vl, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Тут

`if Printer.Printers = PrinterName then`

надо указать индекс строки Printer.Printers**[i]**.